# How can i reverse n chars in string when default value for n is lenght of string?

Tags: c++

I need to create reverse() function that reverse count chars in str.
Here it`s prototype:

```
void reverse(char **str, int count = ???);
```

I need to set default value for count so there will be a full reverse of the line.

I tried to assign this as follows:

```
  void reverse(char **str, int count = strlen(*str))
```

But the compiler showed the following error:

```
error: local variable ‘str’ may not appear in this context
 void reverse(char **str, int count = (int) strlen(*str)) {
```

Here my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>

    using namespace std;

    void reverse(char **str, int count = (int) strlen(*str)) {
        int i;
        char temp;
        for (i = 0; i < count / 2; i++) {
            temp = (*str)[i];
            (*str)[i] = (*str)[count - i];
            (*str)[count - i] = temp;
        }
    }

    int main() {
        char buf[100];
        cout << "Enter your string:\n" << endl;
        cin >> buf;
        char *str;
        str = new char(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(str, buf);

        reverse(&str);
        cout << "Reversed string:\n" << str << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

How can I deal with it?

Comment: `void reverse(char **str, int count = strlen(*str))` -- Honestly, that is one of the most unorthodox function declarations to do a reversal of a string I've ever seen.  This makes more sense: `void reverse(char *str, int count = -1)` and the -1 indicates to reverse the entire string.  What is the reason for `char **` when `char *` is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from what Paul McKenzie said. You don't need a pointer to a pointer to reverse a string in place. A poiinter to a pointer would only be needed if you are trying to change the pointer. But you aren't, you're trying to change what is being pointed to, so a simple pointer is all that is required.

And default values for parameters must be constants, not function calls.

And you're off by one in your algorithm, in `str[count - i]` when `i` is zero you index `str[count]` which is past the end of the string.

Try this

```
void reverse(char *str, int count = -1)
{
    if (count < 0)
        count = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++)
    {
        char temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[count - i - 1];
        str[count - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C++, if you use the `std::string` instead of `char *` the reversal with a default of the whole string (or the first `count` characters if provided) becomes as simple as:

```
std::string reverse (const std::string& s, size_t count = 0)
{
    if (count > s.length())
        count = 0;
    if (count)
        count = s.length() - count;
    return std::string (s.rbegin() + count, s.rend());
}
```

A short example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string reverse (const std::string& s, size_t count = 0)
{
    if (count > s.length())
        count = 0;
    if (count)
        count = s.length() - count;
    return std::string (s.rbegin() + count, s.rend());
}

int main (void)
{
    std::string s("123456789");
    std::string r = reverse(s);
    std::cout << "s\n" << s << "\n\nreverse(s)\n" << r 
                << "\n\nreverse(s, 2)\n";
    r = reverse(s, 2);
    std::cout << r << "\n\nreverse(s, s.length() - 1)\n";
    r = reverse(s, s.length() - 1);
    std::cout << r << '\n';
}
```

(see: [std::basic_string::rend, std::basic_string::crend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend) and [std::basic_string::rbegin, std::basic_string::crbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin))

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strrev
s
123456789

reverse(s)
987654321

reverse(s, 2)
21

reverse(s, s.length() - 1)
87654321
```

**Always Printing The Full-Length Of Characters**

If you only want to reverse `count` characters, but print the full length of the resulting string with just those reversed, you can do something similar to:

```
std::string reverse (const std::string& s, size_t count = 0)
{
    if (count > s.length())
        count = 0;
    if (count) {
        count = s.length() - count;
        return std::string (s.rbegin() + count, s.rend()) + suffix;
    }
    return std::string (s.rbegin() + count, s.rend());
}
```

**All Chars**

```
$ ./bin/strrev
s
123456789

reverse(s)
987654321

reverse(s, 2)
213456789

reverse(s, s.length() - 1)
876543219
```

The containers library provides a number of benefits over using fundamental types.

Answer (score 0):

so it should work this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void reverse(char *str) {
    int count = (int)strlen(str);
    char temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++) {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[count - i-1];
        str[count - i-1] = temp;
    }
}

int main() {
    char buf[100];
    cout << "Enter your string:\n" << endl;
    cin >> buf;
    char *str;
    str = new char(strlen(buf)+1);
    strcpy(str, buf);

    reverse(str);
    cout << "Reversed string:\n" << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You just need to give the function the string and not a pointer to a string. A char** is too much, you can change the chars because u already have a char* pointer. If you dont give the length of the string to the function you cant make any mitakes. I call the strlen function in reverse, thi adds up one O(n) of time complexity, hich isnt that problematic, becaue your function already run in O(n). If you wonder why i used str[count -i-1], that because cString are 0-Terminated, which means that a string "hallo" is actually ""hallo\0", with the -1 literal, you make sure to dont change this '\0' which is needed to terminate the cString.